# `git add *` offers fatal error

Tags: git, version-control, version, addition

It had no problem adding thousands of these types of files but then fatal errors on this one?

```
error: short read Invalid argument
error: Src/Client/Assets/2-Art/Textures/PC/OgreMale/ogmft0302.bmp.meta: failed t
o insert into database
error: unable to index file Src/Client/Assets/2-Art/Textures/PC/OgreMale/ogmft03
02.bmp.meta
fatal: adding files failed
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have read permissions and that the file was not deleted?

Comment: I'm currently on my Windows partition and ran the cmd prompt as an Administrator.  The file is what I imagine is equivalent to chmod 0777.  The file is definitely there, this is the initial add.

Comment: I'd just like to say that 7zip experienced a fatal error zipping up the project, on another file though.  Probably related?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that a process (like the `7zip` one) is still keeping an handle on that specific file, making another process (like `git`) unable to access/read said file.

Try doing that operation again with as many applications closed as you can (or even just after a reboot), in order to see if the error still persists.

Comment: Closing the editor with the opened project fixed the problem for me, thanks for the tip!